# Rich Picklist + A4j Support + onlistchange

Tags: ajax, richfaces, ajax4jsf, picklist

There are a weird behavior happening when I use rich picklist component attached to an a4j support onlistchange event.

If I have "n" selected items into picklist component, the server will try to populate it "n" times (running gruposDeTributosQuery.resultListOrdered() "n" times!!!)! 
This causes a hard delay, because the query used to populate is a little bit slower...
Above is my code:

```
<rich:pickList id="picklisttributos" value="#{criarEstudo.tributosDoAssuntoList}"
label="Tributos" >
<s:selectItems var="_tributos" value="#{gruposDeTributosQuery.resultListOrdered}"
label="#{_tributos.nome} | #{_tributos.id}" />
<s:convertEntity />
<a4j:support event="onlistchange" process="picklistOF" reRender="picklistOF" />
</rich:pickList>
```

Answer (score 0):

Bizarre.
New discover...
The problem is gruposDeTributosQuery.resultListOrdered!

```
 public List<Tributo> getResultListOrdered() {
    this.setOrder("nome");
    //ArrayList<Tributo> lista = new ArrayList<Tributo>(
    //      this.getResultList());
    return this.getResultList();
  }
```

If I use direclty resultList this bahavior doesn´t happen!